# Python code to batch convert multiple non-csv files to csv files in a given directory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, glob

I am trying to batch convert anything other than a csv in a given directory to csv files(In this case, dat, txt files with the same filename)

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os
parent_dir = 'c/path'
for dat_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(parent_dir, '*.dat')):
    #print (dat_file)
    fln = print(os.path.basename(dat_file))
    #print(fln)
    df = pd.read_csv(fln + ".dat", sep='|', header=None)
    hdr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    df.to_csv(fln + ".csv", header=hdr, index=False)

for txt_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(parent_dir, '*.txt')):
        #print (txt_file)
        fln = print(os.path.basename(txt_file))
        #print(fln)
        df = pd.read_csv(fln + ".txt", sep='', header=None)
        hdr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        df.to_csv(fln + ".csv", header=hdr, index=False)
```

But when I am trying to execute, it says, although the syntax seems correct.

**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'**

Comment: You have print statement instead of file path. Print doesn't return anything so you can't do `print(os.path.basename(dat_file)) + ".dat"`

Comment: thank you so much, i removed the print :)